# Confusion with C++ const

Tags: c++, constants

I’m reading the C++ Primer. There is a little confusion I encountered in the ‘const’ subsection and I really hope someone can help me clarifying it.

Here is paraphrasing from the book:

> Among the operations that don’t change the value of an object is initialization—
> when we use an object to initialize another object, it doesn’t matter whether either or
> both of the objects are consts:

```
int i = 42;
const int ci = i; // ok: the value in i is copied into ci
int j = ci; // ok: the value in ci is copied into j
```

> Although ci is a const int, the value in ci is an int. The constness of ci
> matters only for operations that might change ci. When we copy ci to initialize j,
> we don’t care that ci is a const. Copying an object doesn’t change that object. Once
> the copy is made, the new object has no further access to the original object.

Every sentence is clear except for the last one:

> Once the copy is made, the new object has no further access to the original object.

My confusion is: In this context, what is new object, what is original object and why does the new object have no further access to the original object.

I hope I made my point clear. Thanks!

Comment: Just ignore that sentence. It's just language lawyer speak for "the copy is a completely different object from the original".

Comment: It's like copying files: if one file is readonly and you copy it to another location you can do with the copy whatever you want without affecting the original (readonly) file

Comment: It's just trying to say that when you make a copy you get a separate object. That might seem obvious but a very large number of beginners get confused about this. For example `T x = y;`, `x` and `y` are different objects, changes to `x` do not affect `y` (and vice versa).

Comment: It just means that the copy is a completely different object from the original, so any operation done on the copy does not affect the original, and operations on the original don't affect the copy. C++ is different from some other programming languages in that, by default, the act of copying creates a distinct object  (as distinct from some languages where, by default, initialising one object with another means the second object refers to the original, so changing the copy affects the original, and changing the original affects the copy).

Answer (score 1):

objects are instances of classes as represented in memory. You will encounter much more about objects when you get deeper into C++ and OOD. All you need to know is when you create a copy like this:

```
int j = ci;
```

you are creating a second instance of the int class, which resides at a different memory address and has its own value. This is called a "deep copy", and that is the reason (non-const) j is still const correct. No matter what happens to j (new object) after this, ci (original object) will remain unchanged. I hope that helps, don't get discouraged as again you will be spending a lot of time on OOD and object principles.

Answer (score 0):

> what is new object, what is original object

The new object is the one which has just been declared and constructed.  For example:

```
SomeType newObj = originalObj;
```

> why does the new object have no further access to the original object

`newObj` has no way to "look again" at `originalObj`, for example it cannot find out when `originalObj` has changed, nor can it change `originalObj`.  But if `SomeType`'s constructor takes `originalObj` by reference, it actually can access `originalObj` any time, if it stores the reference or a pointer to it inside `newObj`.